# Android HttpClient Trust every Cert my browser trusts

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, truststore

Is there a way to access the Truststore/ The Certificates that my Browsers/ Java / "the System" trust in an App?

In other words, if I host a website under https://test.domain.com and the user chooses to trust the certificate the Server presents (Own CA / Selfsigned), I want my App, accessing this Server, to recognize that The User choose to trust this certificate in his browser allready and therefore trust it too.

I only seem to find Solutions of the Kind: Load a truststore from ressources / Filesystem or trust all certificates.

What i would most like is something like "Android.System.getTruststore()" (simplified to show the idea) or the path where the System keeps its trusted certificates that i can access in an App.

As I am far from a professional i do not even know if there is a single spot where all these certificates are stored or if this is accessable from a 3rd party app^^.

I hope the question is somehow clear and thank for any hints!

Comment: Im not sure how but if we get hold of the browser keystore and use the same in our app then i believe it is possible. I am trying to find how an application can share the browser keystore.